# MySQL SQL syntax error problem?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I get the following error below and was wondering how can I fix it?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.user_id WHERE
users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0) WHERE users.active' at line 4
```

And here is my MySQL code (line breaks inserted so line 4 in error message corresponds to 8).

```
SELECT users.user_id, articles_comments.article_id, articles_comments.comment,
           articles_comments.comment_id
  FROM users_articles
 INNER JOIN articles_comments
            ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
 INNER JOIN (SELECT *
               FROM users INNER JOIN users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
               WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0)
 WHERE users.active IS NULL
   AND users.deletion = 0
 ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Learn to use table aliases - it allows you to shrink the SQL a lot.

Comment: i posted some tutorial that you can learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT users.user_id, articles_comments.article_id, articles_comments.comment, articles_comments.comment_id
FROM users_articles
INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN users_articles ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0) x
WHERE x.active IS NULL
AND x.deletion = 0
ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Explanation:

```
INNER JOIN users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
```

This is an issue. You forgot to specify joined table and keyword `ON`

**UPD**: try this query. It should do the same stuff but much more readable

```
    SELECT *
      FROM users_articles a
INNER JOIN articles_comments c ON c.article_id = a.id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
                  AND u.active IS NULL
                  AND u.deletion = 0
  ORDER BY c.date_created DESC
     LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Now I get Every derived table must have its own alias?

Comment: (SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN users_articles.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0) AS derived

Comment: i've added `x` alias. by the way - the more correct way will be to describe what you want to get, because this query is terrible :-S

Comment: @zerkms I will ask that as my next question then.

Comment: Now I got the following error Duplicate column name 'user_id' :(

Comment: @blah: i've rewritten it. try the query from **UPD**

Comment: @zerkms The UPD query wont check for the fields `AND u.active IS NULL AND u.deletion = 0`

Comment: @blah: It is checked in the `ON` clause

Comment: @zerkms no it doesn't I see results that should not appear:(

Comment: @blah: Give the sample output that my query returns. And explain what is wrong there.

Comment: @zerkms All users and there comments that are marked for `u.deletion = 1` 1 equals deletion should NOT appear as well as users and their comments that have not activated their account `u.active IS NOT NULL` IS NOT NULL equals not activated.

Comment: @blah: please - provide query result, i cannot get what you're trying to describe. There are 2 conditions about active and deletion.

Comment: how can I provide the query result then?

Comment: @blah: edit your question and add few lines with the only key columns, that do not satisfy your expectations.

Comment: you lost me an example would help me understand what you are talking about?

Comment: @blah: scroll to the top and add edit your question ;-) add result with lines that do not fit the conditions. ;-)

Comment: but all you will be able to see is the comments

Comment: @blah: so? do you want to get help or not? :-) my query supposed to work the same as yours. I do not have another information about how it should work, and your attempts to describe failed to me :-S

Comment: I' try to work out the problem my self for right now and if i get stuck again I'll ask a new question thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2):

missing "ON" at :

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN users_articles ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id WHERE users.active IS NULL AND users.deletion = 0)
```

you can more understand with [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?bw=1280#560)